Find a recurrence relation for the sequence b_n
Question:
Let's consider words formed from the alphabet { $a, b, c, d, e, f, g$ }. Let $b_n$ be the number of words of length $n ≥ 0$ that do not contain two consecutive vowels. Find a recurrence relation for the sequence $b_n$. Provide appropriate initial conditions. Solve the recurrence equation.
My process:
I would start by stating that words of length 0 and 1 are
$$b_0 = 1$$
$$b_1 = 7$$
Then I would say that if the last letter isn't vowel we would have $5$ ways of making that word. So that gives us $5b_{n-1}$. Then I would say that if the last letter is is vowel we would have $2 \cdot 5$ ways. So that gives us $10b_{n-2}$. So this would mean that
$$b_n = 5b_{n-1} + 10b_{n-2}$$
But i'm not sure if this is enough and if I can say that there is 1 word with 0 letters.

computing a few small examples (tiss 3 or 4) may help

First, some calculations by hand: $$b_0=1$$ $$b_1=7$$ $$b_2=7^2-2^2=45$$ $$b_3=7^3-2^2\cdot5\cdot2-2^3=295$$ $$b_4=7^4-2^2\cdot3\cdot5^2-2^3\cdot4\cdot5-2^4=1925.$$
Now, about the recursion formula. We want to write $b_{n+1}$ as an expression of previous terms. Suppose we have a word $W$ of length $n$ and we want to add a letter to the end of the word. If $W$ ends with a consonant ($5$ ways to choose one), then any letter can be added ($7$ ways to choose one). The first $n-1$ letters can be anything, so the number of combinations is $b_{n-1}$.
If $W$ ends with a vowel ($2$ ways to choose one), then the previous letter must be a consonant ($5$ ways to choose one). The first $n-2$ letters can be anything ($b_{n-2}$ combinations). We can only add a consonant as the $n+1$-st letter ($5$ ways to choose one).
In total, we get $$b_{n+1}=5\cdot7b_{n-1}+2\cdot5\cdot5b_{n-2}=35b_{n-1}+50b_{n-2}.$$
Let us solve this recursion. Its characteristic equation is $$\lambda^3-35\lambda-50=0.$$ It is equivalent to $$(\lambda+5)(\lambda^2-5\lambda-10)=0.$$ The solution to the equation is $$\lambda=-5, \quad\lambda=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{65}}2.$$
So, $$b_n=a(-5)^n+b \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{65}}2\right)^n +c \left(\frac{5+\sqrt{65}}2\right)^n$$ for some $a,b,c$. Putting $n=0,1,2$, we get the system of equations:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
a+b+c&=1\\
-5a+\frac{(5-\sqrt{65})b}2+\frac{(5+\sqrt{65})c}2&=7\\
25a+\frac{(90-10\sqrt{65})b}4+\frac{(90+10\sqrt{65})c}4&=45
.\end{align}\right.$$
Solving it, we get $$a=0, \quad b=\frac12-\frac9{2\sqrt{65}},\quad c= \frac12+\frac9{2\sqrt{65}}.$$
The answer is then $$b_n= \left(\frac12-\frac9{2\sqrt{65}}\right) \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{65}}2\right)^n + \left(\frac12+\frac9{2\sqrt{65}}\right) \left(\frac{5+\sqrt{65}}2\right)^n, n\ge0.$$

Just to check.

The fact that OP's characteristic equation divides yours and that $a=0$ suggests that OP may have been correct.  Do you see anything wrong with their reasoning?

@Teepeemm It seems to me, OP is correct.
